# How do I execute a jQuery method on an element added to the page via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am inserting a form into the DOM via an AJAX request through jQuery. I am using the typeahead jQuery function provided by the Twitter Bootstrap framework for live searching, and I would like to attach it to the input fields when the `input` elements enter the DOM. To do that, I need to call the `typeahead` method on the input field, but I can't figure out how to make that happen (except on the initial page load).

How do I listen for the input fields to be added to the DOM and call a jQuery method on them at that time?

**UPDATE**

I wasn't specific enough with my question. What I'd like to know if how to call jQuery method only once per element load into the DOM. Since it's an `<input />` tag that I'm watching for, I decided to call the method every time there was a focus event on the item.

```
$("#your_div").on "focus", "input[name='your_name_here']", (event) ->
  $(this).typeahead
    source: ...
```

This works, but is called on every focus when it really only needs to get called on the load of the element.

Comment: Did you try calling the `typeahead` inside of your Ajax request's callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `$.live()` function in jQuery. I had this problem too, but it's a little confusing. Here's an example of how it might work
**EDIT** `$.live()` is outdated, I have edited my answer, thanks to one of the comments below to use the updated `$.on()` function.

```
$("div").on("form.html",function(data){
    //Blah Blah
    });
});
$(function(){
    ("divthatloaded").on("listener",function(){ //By listener I mean click, hover, mouseon, etc...
    //Does stuff to it...
    });
});
```

Really, just use the `$.on` with the appropriate listener/callback to use a div that is loaded by ajax

Comment: I haven't time to write up an answer, but note that `live` is outdated, and that the `on` function provides the behaviour required in a nicer way than `live`.

Comment: I will edit my answer, you are right, I am just so used to live. It does the same thing, on I believe it can be used the same way

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to just call the method one time on the the typeahead `<input />` that is added to the DOM. I'm calling the jQuery typeahead method on `focus` which works fine, but feels inefficient since it doesn't need to be called again every time. I'd love if someone could describe how to call that method only one time per target element load, but I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Try:
`$("#your_div").on("focus", function (event){
    $("input[name='your_name_here']").typeahead();
});​`